# Why are the data records read incorrectly into a List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

Does anyone have an idea why the source code has the following behavior (there are only two data sets after an inner join): The two data sets are read correctly. But now I have the second dataset as result in both datasets. I just can't figure it out.

```
        for (int x = 0; x < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            tasks.ID = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["ID"];
            tasks.UserID = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["UserID"];
            tasks.Aufgabe = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Aufgabe"];
            tasks.Start = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Start"];
            tasks.Ende = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Ende"];
            tasks.Erledigt = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Erledigt"] == DBNull.Value) ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Erledigt"];
            tasks.AufgabenID = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x][6];
            tasks.Bezeichnung = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Bezeichnung"].ToString();
            tasks.Beschreibung = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Beschreibung"].ToString();
            tasks.Zeitrahmen = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Zeitrahmen"];
            tasks.Wert = (decimal)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Wert"];
            tasks.WertGutschrift = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["WertGutschrift"];
            tasks.Folgeaufgabe = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Folgeaufgabe"];
            taskList.Add(tasks);
        }
```

Comment: Because `tasks` is a reference type, not a value type. I.e, you are not copying the values of the task into the list, but always the same and only task reference. After the loop, all list elements point to the same unique task object.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding the same object several times. Create a new one in every iteration (as first line in the for loop):

```
Task tasks = new Task();
```

You set all properties of one object and add it to the list. In the next iteration of the loop, you update the existing object with new values and add it again to the list.

P.S: Don't forget to remove  the line, where you are creating the object right now, or you will get a compiler error.